# Activity st.stxma.Activities.SelectDeviceActivity has leaked IntentReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, receiver

How and where do I unregister the receiver? I searched and found that you do this in the `onPause` and `onCreate` methods but in my situation how would I do that?

```
08-21 10:32:02.291  12817-12817/st.stxma E/ActivityThread﹕
    Activity st.stxma.Activities.SelectDeviceActivity has leaked IntentReceiver
    st.stxma.STXmaBluetooth$1@41d763e8 that was originally registered here.
    Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked:
    Activity st.stxma.Activities.SelectDeviceActivity has leaked IntentReceiver
    st.stxma.STXmaBluetooth$1@41d763e8 that was originally registered here.
    Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:809)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:610)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1803)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1783)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1777)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:479)
        at st.stxma.STXmaBluetooth.enableBluetooth(STXmaBluetooth.java:72)
        at st.stxma.Activities.SelectDeviceActivity.scanForDevices(SelectDeviceActivity.java:90)
        at st.stxma.Activities.SelectDeviceActivity.scanForDevices(SelectDeviceActivity.java:101)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19431)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5598)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### SelectDeviceActivity.java

```
package st.stxma.Activities;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import st.stxma.R;
import st.stxma.STXmaApplication;



public class SelectDeviceActivity extends Activity implements Observer
{

    private STXmaApplication stx_app;
    private LinearLayout device_list;
    private Button disconnect_button;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.w("STXma", "onCreate: Create!");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_device_relative_layout);
        stx_app = (STXmaApplication)getApplicationContext();
        stx_app.getModel().addObserver(this);

        device_list = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.device_list);
        disconnect_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button);

        populateDevices();         
    }

    public void onPause()
    {
        Log.w("STXma", "onPause: Halt Discovery!");
        super.onPause();
        stx_app.getControl().stxBluetooth().haltDiscovery();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        Log.w("STXma", "onResume: Resume!");
        super.onResume();

        setDisconnectButton();
    }

    void dummyDevice(View v)
    {
        //Intent launch_device = new Intent(v.getContext(), DynamicControlActivity.class);
        Intent launch_device = new Intent(v.getContext(), DynamicControlViewPager.class);
        startActivity(launch_device);
    }

    /*public void launchDevice(View v)
    {
        //Intent launch_device = new Intent(v.getContext(), DynamicControlActivity.class);
        Intent launch_device = new Intent(v.getContext(), DynamicControlViewPager.class);
        startActivity(launch_device);
    }*/

    void scanForDevices()
    {
        //  0.  Clear existing buttons
        stx_app.getModel().clearDeviceList();
        device_list.removeAllViews();

        //  1.  Turn on Bluetooth
        stx_app.getControl().stxBluetooth().enableBluetooth(this);



        //  2.  Scan for devices
        stx_app.getControl().stxBluetooth().startDiscovery();
    }

    public void scanForDevices(View v)
    {
        scanForDevices();
    }

    void setDisconnectButton()
    {

        BluetoothDevice dev = stx_app.getModel().getConnectedDevice();

        if(dev == null) {

            disconnect_button.setText("Not Connected");

        }else{

            disconnect_button.setText("Disconnect "+dev.getName());
        }
    }

    void populateDevices()
    {
        device_list.removeAllViews();
        BluetoothDevice devices[] = stx_app.getModel().getDevices();

        if(devices == null)
        {
            device_list.addView(createDummyButton());
            return;
        }

        for(BluetoothDevice dev : devices)
        {
            device_list.addView(createDeviceButton(dev));
        }
    }

    public void update(Observable obs, Object arg)
    {
        BluetoothDevice dev = stx_app.getModel().getLastDeviceAdded();
        device_list.addView(createDeviceButton(dev));
    }

    private Button createDummyButton()
    {
        Button b = new Button(this);
        Drawable button_icon = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.st360);
        if (button_icon != null) {
            button_icon.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
        }
        b.setCompoundDrawables(button_icon, null, null, null);

        b.setText("Dummy Device");

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                dummyDevice(v);
            }
        });

        return b;
    }

    private Button createDeviceButton(BluetoothDevice dev)
    {
        Button b = new Button(this);
        Drawable button_icon = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.st360);
        if (button_icon != null) {
            button_icon.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
        }
        b.setCompoundDrawables(button_icon, null, null, null);


        if ((dev.getName() != null) && (dev.getName().length() > 0)) {
            b.setText(dev.getName());
        }else{
            b.setText("Dummy Device");
        }

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Button b = (Button)v;
                BluetoothDevice dev = stx_app.getModel().getDeviceByName(b.getText().toString());

                if(dev != null)
                {
                    //  Attempt to connect to the device
                    if(stx_app.getControl().connectDevice(dev))
                    {
                        Intent launch_device = new Intent(v.getContext(), DynamicControlViewPager.class);
                        startActivity(launch_device);
                    }
                    else Toast.makeText(SelectDeviceActivity.this, "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return b;
    }

    public void disconnectFromDevice(View v)
    {
        stx_app.getControl().disconnect();
        setDisconnectButton();
    }
}
```

### STXmaBluetooth.java

```
package st.stxma;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;


public class STXmaBluetooth 
{
    final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    BluetoothAdapter bt_adapter;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    BluetoothSocket bt_socket;
    STXmaModel stx_model;
    Boolean connected = false;
    CommunicationThread comm_thread;
    ArrayList<String> message_fragment;

    public STXmaBluetooth(STXmaModel model)
    {
        bt_adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        stx_model = model;
        message_fragment = new ArrayList<String>();

        createReceiver();
    }


    public boolean enableBluetooth(Activity blue_activity)
    {
        Intent enable_bluetooth;
        //  Check to see if the device supports Bluetooth

        if(bt_adapter == null)
        {

            Toast.makeText(blue_activity.getApplicationContext(), "No bluetooth detected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            blue_activity.finish();
            //  Device does not support bluetooth - do something!
        }

        //  Check to see if the Bluetooth is enabled
        //  If not, ask the user if they want to enable it
        if(!bt_adapter.isEnabled())
        {

            enable_bluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            blue_activity.startActivityForResult(enable_bluetooth, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

        }

        //  Enable Receiver

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        blue_activity.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);


        return true;
    }


    private void createReceiver()
    {
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                //Log.w("STXma", "OnReceive called");
                //aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
                {
                    //  Get the Bluetooth device object from the Intent
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    stx_model.addDevice(device);



                }
            }
        };
    }

    public void haltDiscovery()
    {

        bt_adapter.cancelDiscovery();

    }

    public boolean disconnect()
    {
        try
        {
            comm_thread.disconnect();
            bt_socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.w("STXma", "disconnect(): "+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        Log.w("STXma", "Disconnected Now");
        stx_model.setConnectedDevice(null);
        return true;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  ************************************************************************
    //
    //  boolean connect(BluetoothDevice dev)
    //
    //  July 10th, 2014
    //
    //  This function creates a connection to the bluetooth device provided to
    //  it.  It returns true if successful.
    //
    //  Note:  enableCommunicationsThread() must be called to to open the device
    //  for communications.
    //
    //  ************************************************************************
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public boolean connect(BluetoothDevice dev)
    {
        bt_adapter.cancelDiscovery();
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

        try
        {
            bt_socket = dev.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            bt_socket.connect();
            stx_model.setConnectedDevice(dev);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.w("STXma", "IOException in connect "+e.getMessage());
            connected = false;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.w("STXma", "Exception in connect "+e.getMessage());
            connected = false;
        }

        if(connected)
        {
            Log.w("STXma", "Connection completed");
        }

        connected = enableCommunicationsThread();

        return connected;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  ************************************************************************
    //
    //  boolean enableCommunicationsThread()
    //
    //  July 10th, 2014
    //
    //  This function creates and starts the communication thread.  Once started
    //  commands can be sent to the device and the software will read the BT
    //  responses
    //
    //  ************************************************************************
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private boolean enableCommunicationsThread()
    {
        comm_thread = new CommunicationThread(bt_socket, this);
        comm_thread.start();
        return comm_thread.isConnected();        
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  ************************************************************************
    //
    //  void sendCommand(String cmd)
    //
    //  July 10th, 2014
    //
    //  Converts the string command into an integer and sends it to the
    //  communication thread to be writen to the device.
    //
    //  ************************************************************************
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void sendCommand(String cmd)
    {
        try
        {
            int i = Integer.decode(cmd);
            comm_thread.write(i); 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.w("STXma", "Send Command Failed: "+e.getMessage());
        }        
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  ************************************************************************
    //
    //  public void startDiscovery()
    //
    //  July 7th, 2014
    //
    //  This function clears the existing list of devices then starts the
    //  discovery process.
    //
    //  ************************************************************************
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void startDiscovery()
    {
        Log.w("STXma", "Start Discovery");
        bt_adapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    public void processBuffer(Integer[] buffer)
    {
        //Log.w("STXma", "Process Buffer");

        for(int value : buffer)
        {
            String byte_string = Integer.toHexString(value);
            Log.w("STXma", "0x"+byte_string);


            message_fragment.add(byte_string);
            if(completedMessage())
            {
                String byte_array[] = new String[message_fragment.size()];
                byte_array = message_fragment.toArray(byte_array);

                stx_model.processBluetoothMessage(byte_array);

                //  Clear the messages
                message_fragment.clear();
            }

        }

    }   

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  ************************************************************************
    //
    //  boolean completedMessage()
    //
    //  July 21, 2014
    //
    //  There are three valid return sizes
    //  4X - These are all five byte messages.  The first is the command, the
    //      other four bytes are the data
    //  8X - These are two byte messages returned separately.  The first byte
    //      tells the device what is being set, the second is the value it
    //      sets it to
    //  XX - These are command bytes that are a single byte long
    //
    //  ************************************************************************
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private boolean completedMessage()
    {
        //  If the message_fragment is empty, we do not have a valid return
        if(message_fragment.isEmpty())return false;

        //  If the first byte starts with a "4", we know we have a 5 byte
        //  return, so we need to collect 5 bytes before returning true
        String first = message_fragment.get(0);
        if(first.startsWith("4")) {
            return message_fragment.size() == 5;
        }
        else if(first.startsWith("8"))
        {
            return message_fragment.size() == 2;
        }

        //  Any other size is a valid single byte command return
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method `onDestroy()` and put inside `unregisterReceiver(broadcast)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do i create the onDestroy() method  inside the bluetooth class? I am confused on where to put this method?

Comment: Create it in the class where you want to unregisterReceiver it. preferably in all the classes create a method `onDestroy()` and unregisterReceiver it

Comment: But how do i unregister the receiver from the SelectDeviceActivity.java class when the receiver is being registered in the STXmaBluetooth.java class  class?  if you look at the top in the code you will see how its being registered in the enabledBluetooth method in the STXmaBluetooth class. can you please provide an example?

Comment: Could you please like try shortening the code to only the part with the broadcast receive. And you unregister it like this. `unregisterReceiver(**name of the broadcast receiver instance that is the name of the variable you created as an instance of your broadcast receiver**)`

Comment: `IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        blue_activity.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);`

Comment: Ok thanks. Now the thing is whenever you want to unregister it put the code in above above comment